# How to convert a serial number that was initially a date to the number of days that the date initially had but without using the date object?

Tags: javascript, date

First you have a serial number which was converted from a date, for example : 40988 would be March 21st 2012.
How could I then return **21** knowing that the serial number is 40988 and by **NOT** using the date object? I also have 2 other functions that I can use : numberOfDaysYear(year) which returns the number of days for a specific year (365 or 366) and I also have numberOfDaysMonth(month, year) which returns the number of days for a specific month and a specific year (31, 30, 28 or 29). The year limit goes from 1900 all the way to 2199, so this is what I started with

`

```
  //Count the number of 365 years and 366 years

  var counterNormalYears = 0
  var counterLeapYears = 0

  for (let i = 1900; i <= 2199; i++) {
     if (numberOfDaysYear(i) == 365) {
        counterNormalYears += 1
     }
     else if (numberOfDaysYear(i) == 366) {
        counterLeapYears += 1
     }
  }
```

`
Moving on from here what kind of approach could I take to then find the days that the date has without using the date object?

Comment: `NOT using the date object` - why? it's there in javascript. it's a tool, use it

Comment: @Bravo—because it's totally unnecessary. The formula for working out if a year is leap or not is pretty simple, so if it's leap, add 366, otherwise add 365.

Comment: I'd write the expression as a ternary expression: `numberOfDaysYear(i) == 366? ++counterLeapYears : ++counterNormalYears`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do it like

```
let day = 40988, year = 1899, month = 0;
while (day > 0) day -= numberOfDaysYear(++year);
day += numberOfDaysYear(year);
while (day > 0) day -= numberOfDaysMonth(++month, year);
day += numberOfDaysMonth(month, year);
```

To explain ...

1. start at 1899, because I use pre-increment for obvious reasons
2. first thing that happens is the number of days in 1970 (using YOUR function) is subtracted from days ... since I use pre-increment, 1970 is passed in on the first loop
3. since we've gone below zero, add that last number of days in the last used `year` back to `days`
4. similar algorithm for month - subtract from days until below zero
5. similar backtrack for month as in step 3
6. you may need to adjust `day` by 2 - because of maths

had an issue in the original code ... but this should work

I much prefer using Date though

```
d = new Date('1900-01-01');
d.setDate(40988 + 1); // because of maths 
// done
```

Comment: Could I ask why you initialize year to 1969?

Comment: Code–only answers aren't that helpful. You need to explain the algorithm.

Comment: yeah, sure, @RobG, but the code uses OP's functions so, what's left to explain?

Comment: oh, wait ... sorry, that 40988 is since 1900 ... let me rewrite

Comment: @alexhorga - some tweaks may be needed though :p (day need to have 2 subtracted at the end I think

Comment: @Bravo-Your algorithm works great except some serial numbers don't exactly return the right number of days for example 72500 should return 30 but for me it returns 0. Also if the serial is 17500 it should return 30 but it returns 0 so it's probably a small bug somewhere...

Comment: Probably because the second `while (day >= 0)` should've been a `while (day > 0)`  @night - actually BOTH should've been `>` rather than `>=`

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the other functions so I've mocked them. A simple method is to count the days for each year since 1900 until there are fewer than 1 year's days left. Then count the days for each month until there are fewer than 1 month's days left. The remaining days are the day in the month.

The *daysToDate* function returns an array of [year, month, day] as numbers to make it more useful. If you just want the day, just get the last element. In the example, I've turned the values into a YYYY-MM-DD timestamp.

It does minimal validation of input, likely a bit more is required.

```js
// Return true if year is a leap year
function isLeap(year) {
  return !(year % 4 || !(year % 100) && year % 400); 
}

// Return number of days in year
function daysInYear(year) {
  return isLeap(year)? 366 : 365;
}

// Return number of days in month
// Month is calendar month number
function daysInMonth(year, month) {
  if (month == 2 && isLeap(year)) {
    return 29;
  }
  return [,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][month];
}

// Convert days since 1900 to [year, month, day]
// Month is calendar month number
// Assumes 1 Jan 1900 is 1
function daysToDate(days) {
  // Ensure days is within range 1990-01-01 to 2199-12-31
  if (days < 1 || days > 109573) {
    return;
  }
  
  let daysCounted = 0;
  let year = 1900;
  
  // Loop over years until less than a year's worth
  // of days left
  while (daysInYear(year) < (days - daysCounted)) {
    daysCounted += daysInYear(year);
    ++year;
  }
  
  let month = 1;
  // Loop over month until less than a month's worth
  // of days left
  while (daysInMonth(year, month) < (days - daysCounted)) {
    daysCounted += daysInMonth(year, month);
    ++month;
  }
  
  return [year, month, days - daysCounted];
}

[ 1,     //  1 Jan 1900
  365,   // 31 Dec 1900
  366,   //  1 Jan 1901 
  730,   // 31 Dec 1901
  40988, // 21 Mar 2012
  109573 // 31 Dec 2199
].forEach(days => console.log(
  days + ': ' + daysToDate(days).map(n=>(n<10?'0':'')+n).join('-')
));
```

Comment: @RobG-this might seem silly but when I use your algorithm it crashes the website that I'm testing it on.

Comment: @alexhorga—do you mean you've copy and pasted the code, or re–written it using the same algorithm? In any case, I can't see why it would do that unless one of the *while* loops is not exiting. Trying putting a limit on it. Just before the loop put `let limit = 20` then add a condition `while (--limit && ... )` so it will only do 20 loops. Or use a debugger to step through the code rather than just running it.

Comment: @RobG-It is in fact not exiting the loop because I debugged it and the month variable had an unrealistically large value so It's most likely looping forever causing the website to crash and not load. I rewrote your algorithm without modifying anything.